# Kronecker's theorem - converse

Tags: diophantine-approximation

I don't know how to prove that Kronecker's theorem is false if $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$, $\dots$, $\alpha_{M}$
are not independent.

> **Kronecker's theorem**
>   Suppose
>   that $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$, $\dots$, $\alpha_{M}$
>   are independent real numbers. Then given real
>   numbers $\beta_{1}$, $\beta_{2}$, $\dots$, $\beta_{M}$
>   and $\epsilon>0$ we can find integers
>   $N$, $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, $\dots$, $m_{M}$ such that
>   $$|N\alpha_{j}-\beta_{j}-m_{j}|<\epsilon$$
>   for each $1\leq j\leq M$.

Where if $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$, $\dots$, $\alpha_{M}$
satisfy

$\sum_{j=1}^{M} n_{j}\alpha_{j}\notin{\mathbb Z}$
for integers $n_{j}$ not all zero

then we say that they are independent real numbers.

It's easy if $M=1$, since then $\alpha_1$ is rational and $N\alpha_1$ only takes finitely many values modulo 1. But I can't get anything done even for $M=2$. I've tried drawing a picture but I'm struggling to get anywhere.

Comment: What *exactly* are "independent real numbers", please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_M$ are not independent, then they satisfy
$$
n_0+\sum_{j=1}^{M} n_{j}\alpha_{j}=0,$$
for integers $n_i$ not all zero.

Then the set $\{( N\alpha_1,\cdots, N\alpha_M)|N\in \mathbb{N}\}$ will be a subset of 
$$
\{(x_1,\cdots, x_n)| \sum_{j=1}^{M} n_{j}x_j =m \textrm{ for some } m\in\mathbb{Z}\}.
$$

The above set is not a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^M$.